# How to wait for process to finish using IO.popen?

Tags: ruby, linux, command-line

I'm using `IO.popen` in Ruby to run a series of command line commands in a loop. I then need to run another command outside of the loop. The command outside of the loop cannot run until all of the commands in the loop have terminated.

How do I make the program wait for this to happen? At the moment the final command is running too soon.

An example:

```
for foo in bar
    IO.popen(cmd_foo)
end
IO.popen(another_cmd)
```

So all `cmd_foos` need to return before `another_cmd` is run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'd need to assign the results from the `IO.popen` calls within the cycle to the variables, and keep calling `read()` on them until `eof()` becomes true on all.

Then you know that all the programs have finished their execution and you can start `another_cmd`.

Comment: Just as an additional note: using the block form of IO methods is usually safer.  Also, in 1.9 you get added robustness because block variables have different scoping which prevents modification of same named variables outside the block (and you'll earn a warning).

Answer (score 23):

Apparently the [canonical way](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4405801#new) to do this is:

```
 Process.wait(popened_io.pid)
```

Comment: This answer is the most correct. No side effects (like with io.read), and very obvious what it's doing.

Comment: It looks like `.close` also waits, as it sets `$?`, and calling `Process.wait` on the pipe's pid after calling `.close` gives an ECHILD error.

Comment: Looks like `#close` basically closes both the "IO and the process" so yeah apparently that works as well, if you don't mind your IO's getting closed https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/6b6ba319ea4a5afe445bad918a214b7d5691fd7c/io.c#L4374

Answer (score 22):

Use the block form and read all the content:

```
IO.popen "cmd" do |io|
  # 1 array
  io.readlines

  # alternative, 1 big String
  io.read

  # or, if you have to do something with the output
  io.each do |line|
    puts line
  end

  # if you just want to ignore the output, I'd do
  io.each {||}
end
```

If you do not read the output, it may be that the process blocks because the pipe connecting the other process and your process is full and nobody reads from it.

Comment: Would `IO.popen('cmd').close` work when discarding stdout? Docs say it sets `$?` (thus waits), but I'm not clear it it also discards all stdout without blocking.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "discarding stdout"? The code you show does not discard anything. If you want to just execute something and not do anything special with the output system() is more appropriate,

Comment: by "discard stdout" I meant "read the output", which this answer said may be required to prevent blocking.

Comment: But what is the goal? Do you really want to discard output? Then you must read it and simply ignore it. In that case system() is not a good alternative unless you would redirect stdout to /dev/null. Generally stdout and stderr must be read because otherwise you risk blocking the process.

Comment: First look in the standard library. It is actually pretty useful.

Comment: I don't think you're "required" to read all the content, when it reaches the end of the block it closes the IO's which effectively flushes them?

Answer (score 6):

```
for foo in bar
  out = IO.popen(cmd_foo)
  out.readlines
end
IO.popen(another_cmd)
```

Reading the output to a variable then calling `out.readlines` did it. I think that `out.readlines` must wait for the process to end before it returns.

Credit to Andrew Y for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I tried the exact same thing and ended up with zombies (defunct), so not ideal

Comment: It is missing out.close

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use `Thread.join` to synchronize the last `popen` call:

```
t = Thread.new do
    for foo in bar
       IO.popen(cmd_foo)
    end
end

t.join

IO.popen(another_cmd)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the output of `popen`? If not, do you want to use `Kernel#system` or some other command?