# Suppressing the output of a command run using 'system' method while running it in a ruby script

Tags: ruby

I am not sure if this makes sense but I am thinking if there is a way to suppress the output shown for a command when run using the `system` method in ruby? I mean it should just output true or false to STDOUT and not the output of the command. What I think is it can just only be done if the command can run silently and not from the `system` method. Can someone provide a bit more insight?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After a call to `system` the exit code is in the special variable `$?` so if `useradd` returns different values to indicate if the user was successfully added (e.g. 0 for success) then you can do the following:

```
system('useradd xx > /dev/null')
if $? == 0
  puts 'added'
else
  puts 'failed'
end
```

where the redirect to `/dev/null` will suppress the output.

Alternatively if the program being called does not use its exit code to indicate success or failure you can use backticks and search for a particular substring in the output e.g.

```
if `useradd xx`.include? 'success'
  puts 'it worked'
else
  puts 'failed to add user'
end
```

Comment: This alone won't suppress `stderr`. Should use this `system('useradd xx > /dev/null 2>&1')`

Comment: `system` also returns `true` or `false` and I especially like to depend on those simple values. The return values are not affected by the `> /dev/null 2>&1` redirection.

Comment: None of these will work on Windows because `/dev/null` doesn't exist, even under Git-Bash. The better answer is to use `out: File::NULL, err: File::NULL`. That's properly portable and clearly indicates intent without having to worry about if you handled `&2>1` vs. `&>` vs whatever.

Answer (score 64):

If you want to take advantage of the variadic form of Kernel.system, which side-steps the many quoting issues with shells, you can use the same [options which Kernel.spawn accepts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn).

**TL;DR - Use `:out => File::NULL` to silence output from Kernel.system**

Arguments with special characters (spaces, etc.) can cause problems with the shell:

```
irb(main):001:0> filename_with_spaces = "foo bar.txt"
=> "foo bar.txt"

irb(main):002:0> system "ls -l #{filename_with_spaces}"
ls: bar.txt: No such file or directory
ls: foo: No such file or directory
=> false
```

So if you are interpolating variables into a system call, it is safer to provide the arguments separately:

```
irb(main):003:0> system "ls", "-l", filename_with_spaces
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody  nobody  9 Feb  1 16:53 foo bar.txt
=> true
```

But now we have a problem if we want to hide the output.

```
irb(main):004:0> system "ls", "-l", filename_with_spaces, "> /dev/null"
ls: > /dev/null: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody  nobody  9 Feb  1 16:53 foo bar.txt
=> false
```

We could close STDOUT using the `:out => :close` option:

```
irb(main):005:0> system "ls", "-l", filename_with_spaces, :out => :close
=> true
```

However, this might cause issues with certain commands which may try to attach to STDOUT.

```
irb(main):006:0> system "echo", "hi there", :out => :close
echo: write: Bad file descriptor
=> false
```

To fix this, we can go back to redirecting our output, using `File::NULL` to remain portable:

```
irb(main):007:0> system "echo", "hi there", :out => File::NULL
=> true
```

Comment: From this answer I was able to deduce `:err =>` as well. Is there something that means both `out:` and `:err`, so I don’t have to write `:out => File::NULL, :err => File::NULL`?

Comment: If you look at documentation for [Kernel#spawn](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn), you'll find that you can do this `[:out, :err] => File::NULL`, as well as many other things.

Comment: @Steve Goddamn that's elegant AF.

Answer (score 8):

As an addendum, I've been surprised a few times when I've used backticks and saw output "slipping past" my variables when running scripts from the command line.

Invariably, the issue is that the text I'm seeing is actually coming from `stderr` rather than `stdout`.  So, to wrangle that text into stdout as well, remember to append `2>&1` to the command you're trying to run.

I hope that's helpful to someone.  I just wasted twenty minutes re-learning this lesson :)

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with this question as well...

Keep in mind that with ruby `system` calls, the UNIX command you are trying to use might offer a "silent" option--nullifying the need to suppress terminal output altogether!

For instance:

```
system 'curl -s "your_params_here"'
```

Will suppress the output that typically accompanies a curl call.

Answer (score 1):

**`IO.popen`**

This is another good option:

```
IO.popen(['echo', 'a']) do |f|
  f.read == "a\n" or raise
end
$?.exitstatus == 0 or raise
```

Nothing will get output to your stdout.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/IO.html#method-c-popen

Comment: TODO does `IO.popen('cmd').close` work as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217351/io-popen-how-to-wait-for-process-to-finish#comment42139826_1236075

Answer (score 0):

- define `null_device`, it's operating systems [dependent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device): **windows** 7 and newer use `nul`, while ***nix** systems uses `/dev/null`
- run the command
- redirect it's standard and error output to `null_device`
- then use the exit code, or the backtick method as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1961119/2245329) by @mikej to determine the output

as follows:

```
 null_device = Gem.win_platform? ? "/nul" : "/dev/null"

 do method
   system "run command 1>#{null_device} 2>#{null_device} "
   p ($? == 0)
 end
```

Comment: Doesn't work, still shows the output

Answer (score -2):

You can also use backticks or %x

Comment: yes but I will not be able to use it as a condition to execute a few statements which I can do when using 'system'

Comment: That makes very little sense so maybe you should post an actual example.

Comment: So write a different conditional that actually parses the output and might be a better idea than what you have now.

Answer (score -4):

This should work

```
system ls, STDOUT:'/dev/null'
```

Comment: This is an invalid argument, so no idea where this comes from.