# hiding system command results in ruby

Tags: ruby, command, system

How easy is it to hide results from system commands in ruby? For example, some of my scripts run

```
system "curl ..."
```

and I would not prefer to see the results of the download.

Comment: Note that curl already has a `--silent` mode you can use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suppressing the output of a command run using 'system' method while running it in a ruby script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960838/suppressing-the-output-of-a-command-run-using-system-method-while-running-it-i)

Answer (score 16):

To keep it working with `system` without modifying your command:

```ruby
system('curl ...', :err => File::NULL)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960838/suppressing-the-output-of-a-command-run-using-system-method-while-running-it-i#answer-35142176)

Comment: +1 Definitely the most elegant and simplest solution, since it uses the `system` function still, and isn't OS-specific.

Comment: You can also use `[ :out, :err ] => File::NULL` if you want to redirect both `out` and `err`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the more sophisticated [popen3](http://apidock.com/ruby/Open3/popen3/class) to have control over STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR separately if you like:

```
Open3.popen3("curl...") do |stdin, stdout, stderr, thread|
  # ...
end
```

If you want to silence certain streams you can ignore them, or if it's important to redirect or interpret that output, you still have that available.

Comment: You may need to "require 'open3'". Use "myvarname = stdin.read" if you want to process output.

Comment: To use advanced outputs like stdin, stderr etc. it's okay, but just to get the output of the console it's a dependency which can be eliminated with e.g. `%x{bash-command arg1 arg2}`

Comment: @RaVeN One advantage of `popen3` or `system` is you can properly break out arguments: `system("example", "--file", user_supplied_filename)` is safe from shell injection. `system("example --file #{user_supplied_filename}")` is **extremely dangerous** and should not be done.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest ways other than popen:

1. Use %x instead of system. It will automatically pipe

   ```
   rval = %x{curl ...}       #rval will contain the output instead of function return value
   ```
2. Manually pipe to /dev/null. Working in UNIX like system, not Windows

   ```
   system "curl ... > /dev/null"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest one is to redirect stdout :)

```
system "curl ... 1>/dev/null"
# same as
`curl ... 1>/dev/null`
```