# Ruby system command is giving me an output

Tags: ruby, multithreading, shell, stdout

This ruby 'system' gives me an output; on irb:

```
system("sudo airodump-ng -w sidney wlan0")
```

Airodump-ng is from the Airocrack-ng package.

However, the ruby "system" should not give me a stdout.
The thing is, that a "sh" processus is being created, which doesn't have an output. But the "sh" processus got a child processus, which gives me a output that I don't want at all to be displayed on my terminal.

Second part of the question, how can I get the pid of that sub-processus, using threads and maybe a different way to call a shell command using ruby (and not displaying the output of that child processus) ?

Comment: I'm not sure this is exactly what you need, but have tried creating a wrapper to get the process and running within this? We've had this problem previously and solved this way. Theres a load of examples on SO http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/wrapper.html

Comment: You don't want *any* output at all?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960838/suppressing-the-output-of-a-command-run-using-system-method-while-running-it-i

Comment: nope, that question and mine are different, and the answers are differents as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the output, trash it:

```
system("sudo airodump-ng -w sidney wlan0 >/dev/null 2>&1")
```

I *think* the child process will inherit the parent's file descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
out = `sudo airodump-ng -w sidney wlan0`
```

instead, and output will not show on screen, but stored in `out` instead

Comment: It doesn't work, the output of the second child is shown.
Please try it on irb, you will see that it is displayed :-(

And here, I would like to retrieve the second child's pid. I can't :/

Comment: @sidney That may mean that airodump-ng is sending stuff to STDERR. Try adding `2>&1` to the above command.