# Suppressing stdout for a system() call in Windows (C)

Tags: c++, c, windows, mingw

[Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960838/suppressing-the-output-of-a-command-run-using-system-method-while-running-it-i) I have a cross platform piece of code which needs to start a separate process, I'm using a system() call for ease of use and because it is cross-platform, but in Windows I can't find a method of stopping the stdout from the system() call going to the terminal window.

This is very annoying as the .exe the system call starts has a lot of pointless outputs which can't be silenced with options.

Here's the code:

```
std::system("wgrib2 C:/Inputs/HRES_ENS_2014032500+000.grib2 -lola -8.0:140:0.1 48.0:140:0.1 C:/Inputs/HRES_ENS_2014032500+000.bin bin -for 2:2:1");
```

In case it makes any difference, I'm using minGW as a compiler.

Comment: cant you redirect the output to a temporary file? isnt it fine for your program?

Comment: Did you try `> NUL` ?  That should suppress output..

Comment: Yes thanks, I've tried that already, but it doesn't entirely work, it passes the standard output from the function ok to a text file (or to NULL) but any warnings that come up still go to the terminal window.

Comment: To suppress errors as well as normal output use `> NUL 2>&1`