# Suppressing Command Prompt output while running a shell command in capture3

Tags: ruby, windows, command-prompt, popen3

I'm running [Amazon's Kindle Previewer](https://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&docId=1000765261) tool in a Ruby script through capture3. The Kindle Previewer command validates an epub file and prints a log to a specified folder, while also printing a log in the terminal as it runs. I do *not* want any of these messages to appear in the terminal though. The syntax for the command itself is `kindlepreviewer [epub file] -log -output [log output folder]`. Within my capture3 statement, it looks like this:

`stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3("kindlepreviewer #{epub_file} -log -output #{output_folder}")`

This executes successfully on both a Mac and a PC, and I'm able to use the output elsewhere in my script. On a Mac, the Terminal window suppresses the output that is generated while the command is running, which is what I want. My problem is that in Windows, all of the output still comes through in Command Prompt. I can't figure out how to turn this off. Based on similar questions such as: [Suppressing the output of a command run using 'system' method while running it in a ruby script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960838/suppressing-the-output-of-a-command-run-using-system-method-while-running-it-i), I tried something like:

`stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3("#{cmd} #{epub} -log -output #{@kindle_folder}  > /dev/null 2>&1")`

This has no effect at all. The executes normally, with all output still appearing in Command Prompt.

I know Kindle Previewer is a very specific tool to be referencing here, but I can't seem to find a more general answer as to why running a capture3 command on a Mac will suppress the output in Terminal, but running it in Windows Command Prompt will not. Is there a different way I should be running shell commands in Ruby on a PC, while still being able to store the command's output in the script?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with a similar problem myself, where I wanted to completely prevent any console output on Windows. Remember that the Windows DOS prompt is not a Bash shell, so you really cannot use the same output redirection syntax.

After trying several different options, I ended up using [`win32/process`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/win32-process/file/README.md), which gives direct access to the Win32 API `CreateProcess` method. Only using this approach was I able to fully prevent ouput:

```
require 'win32/process'

pinfo = Process.create({ command_line:   "program arguments",
                         creation_flags: Process::DETACHED_PROCESS })

# Taken from the win32/process manual, in case you need to wait for the
# spawned process to finish before continuing with the rest of your script:
sleep 0.1 while !Process.get_exitcode(pinfo.process_id)
```

`DETACHED_PROCESS` here is key, as it prevents any access to the originating terminal by the created process.

Use `gem install win32-process` to install this gem.